# What query can i use to fetch data from local storage of selected key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I need to store a lot of data in local storage for my app. I am successful in storing that. Now i need to fetch data in an array but of the selected key/values and not all or just 1 of them. I have named these key as "section"+id as seen below, need to select these in an array.
[image]

Comment: localStorage.getItem(key);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem(key)` will return the data for the key you provide. Data from localStorage is serialized so you need to parse it with `JSON.parse(data)` into a plain JS object and then you can work with it as any other object.

You can only get a single item with `localStorage.getItem` so if you want to get multiple items in an array you'll have to loop and get each one individually and put them in an array.
Maybe something like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});
```

First, we get all the "section###" keys with the `filter` function. Then we create a new array with the data for each corresponding item using the `map` function.

Comment: I need to select keys dynamically something you are explaining above but i am unable to understand this code `/^section\d+$/.test(key);` , in console it says 10 true, 2 false. Can you please guide me how to get these each one in each array so that i can use them further

Comment: @user2828442 It matches all keys that consist of "section" followed by numbers, so it matches "section321", "section323" and so on but it doesn't match keys such as "sectionTypes" or "templateType". It took it from your screenshot that's the pattern you want. This check is used as a condition for the `filter` function so the `keys` array will only contain your "section###" keys for use when getting and parsing the data for all those items.

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for, works like a charm

Comment: i need to fetch the "title" from the object, can you guide me how can i do that, `console.log(dataArray.title);` is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I have edited it.

```
var keys = [];
var data = [];

for (var key in localStorage) {
  if (key.indexOf("section") > -1) 
    keys.push(key);
}

for (var i in keys) {
  data.push(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]))
}
```

Comment: but i dont know the key names, i need to select keys which are section+some no. in a loop, can you now update your solution accordingly

Comment: do you also want to fetch all of their data in array

Comment: @AbhinavS.Chauhan I would put the data.push inside of the first for loop, because of the fact that JavaScript isn't synchronous, thus the last for loop could be executed half way of the first.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan That's completely NOT true, there are no asynchronous actions in this code. `for` loops are completely synchronous.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm My bad. I'd better start reading some stuff again then. I recall someone here on stackoverflow mentioned it one time, so I thought it was for every loop and stuff!

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Maybe you're thinking of a very common issue where people want to have a delay between iterations and think they can accomplish this by putting a `setTimeout()` inside a `for` loop. Your suggestion of pushing the data in the first loop is good anyway though, simply because only one loop is needed in this approach. But the code in this answer is very broken anyway.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Thanks for the extra information and feedback! Always willing to learn. If anyone else is wondering what this is all about, I just found [this](http://latentflip.com/loupe/) link explaining the subject.